# PHP Regular Expression Substring

Tags: php, regex, substring

I have a very long query with a lot of sub-queries in it (almost a thousand lines long).

What I want to do is to get the names of all the tables that are being used in the query. So take the following example of a query just to get an idea:

#### SQL Query

```
$sql = "SELECT
    ...,
    ...,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(t.id) AS t_count
        FROM _user_just_a_table_db_ jat
        WHERE ...
        AND ...
        AND ...
    ),
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
    FROM _user_main_table_db_ tbl
    LEFT JOIN _user_joining_table_db_ jt
    ON jt.id = tbl.jt_id
    WHERE ...
    AND ...
    AND tbl.id IN (
        SELECT at.id
        FROM _user_another_table_db_ at
        WHERE at.active = 'Y'
    )";
```

In this particular situation, I want to get maybe an `array` or a `string` with the following results:

```
just_a_table
main_table
joining_table
another_table
```

#### Notes

1. Please note that the names of the table can appear multiple times. You **may or may not** worry about that as I can easily remove duplicates after getting the resulting `array` or `string`.
2. As you may have already noticed, the list of strings that I want to get will **ALWAYS** be in between `_user_` and `_db_`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aV8hR2/1

Comment: @rock321987 `(_user_.*?_db_)` would get the full table name.

Comment: @apokryfos see the regex once again

Comment: @rock321987 I'm using your regex but I'm getting an error that says `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('`. Here's my code: `preg_match('_user_(.*?)_db_/gm', $sql, $matches);`.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio you're missing the opening regex delimiter

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
_user_(.*?)_db_
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV8hR2/1)**

*PHP code*

```
$match = array();
$re = "/_user_(.*?)_db_/"; 
$str = "SELECT\n    ...,\n    ...,\n    (\n        SELECT COUNT(t.id) AS t_count\n        FROM _user_just_a_table_db_ jat\n        WHERE ...\n        AND ...\n        AND ...\n    ),\n    ...,\n    ...,\n    ...\n    FROM _user_main_table_db_ tbl\n    LEFT JOIN _user_joining_table_db_ jt\n    ON jt.id = tbl.jt_id\n    WHERE ...\n    AND ...\n    AND tbl.id IN (\n        SELECT at.id\n        FROM _user_another_table_db_ at\n        WHERE at.active = 'Y'\n    )\""; 

$res = preg_match_all($re, $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/GnQiku)**

Comment: @chris85 actually I generated the code from `regex101`..Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/_user_(.*)_db_/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $sql, $match);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).